# What does bracket mean in MDN javascript syntax document between each parameters?

Tags: javascript, syntax

I do not understand what all these brackets mean in MDN javascript syntax document.

For example,  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

in this document, there are brackets "[" between each parameter before the comma ','

```
Array.prototype.map()

var new_array = arr.map(function callback(currentValue[, index[, array]]) {
    // Return element for new_array
}[, thisArg])
```

but when i actually code, for example,

```
var numbers = [1, 4, 9];
var info = numbers.map(function(num,index) { 
    return "index: " + index + ", number: " + num;
});

console.log(info)

//output:   ["index: 0, number: 1", "index: 1, number: 4", "index: 2, number: 9"]
```

I do not use array or put [ in the parameters... 
So what does these brackets mean in the document??

[image]

Comment: Its an optional argument. You can ommit it.

Comment: Means optional.

Comment: @YatendrasinhJoddha incorrect

Comment: @JonasW. actually all of them are optional `:)`

Comment: @epascarello Ya sorry. They are optional parameters

Answer (score 7):

These brackets mean **optional** parameters. It means, you don't have to include those parameters.

Example: Lets say I have function for incrementing: `inc(x)` Which **needs** one parameter. When called, it will increment that variable exactly by one. `inc(x)` equals `x++`  But I would like to have an **option** to increment by any number as well. Eg.: `inx(x, 3)` which gives the same result as `x = x + 3`. Then I can describe my function similarly as on MDN as:

```
function inc(variable [,increment])
```

Comment: so for example, if  there is a bracket, everything in [   ]  are optional? or the parameter before the opening bracket?

Comment: so lets have arr.reduce(callback(accumulator, currentValue[, index[, array]])[, initialValue]); should it be like that : arr.reduce(callback(accumulator, currentValue[, index][, array])[, initialValue]) why array parameter in the square brackets of index, it looks like array variable is a parameter of index variable like index(array)

Comment: @O.k - It means, that _array_ parameter can be optional, only if optional parameter _index_ is used. You can use `callback(accumulator, currentValue, index)` or `callback(accumulator, currentValue, index, array)` But not `callback(accumulator, currentValue, array)` Beacuse _array_ parameter comes to play only if _index_ is used

Comment: @LudovitMydla - Great explanation thank you my friend

Comment: That is the reason to use double (triple, quadruple, etc) brackets in this notation: **function A(mandParam1 [, optParamX [, optParamY]])** = **Use optional param Y, only if previous optional param X is used**

Comment: Thanks for that explanation about nested brackets @Ludovit Finally makes sense!